# What is the LOCAL path to a public asset in Laravel 5? (using server.php)

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

I'm using Laravel for the first time, and running into problems with my localhost server.

Once I deploy the site, I can view an image I uploaded at the following address:

> www.mysite.com/storage/img/1.jpg

mysite.com is set to Laravels public folder. Visiting the mysite.com url displays the laravel welcome page.

Now for localhost, which runs using the following command, thus running Laravels server script:

> php -S localhost:4000 server.php

Visiting the localhost:4000 url displays the laravel welcome page. Appending this url with my named routes runs Laravel routes as expected. But I CANNOT access the .jpg I mentioned at any address! Even when referenced within a laravel view.

> http://localhost:4000/storage/img/1.jpg

^returns a 404 not found page

> http://localhost:4000/public/storage/img/1.jpg

^returns the laravel welcome page again!

How do I reference assets, or indeed anything within my public folder, while using the server.php script to set up a local environment? These paths do not work either absolute or relative from within a view. Thanks in advance!

My (unedited) server.php script looks like this:)

```
 <?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
); 

if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Comment: Do you have any **storage** folder inside the **public** directory?

Comment: Yes. /public/storage and /public/storage/img for images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, because in Laravel 5 the storage for blades is in resources and there you will find also the assets folder inside of it the images folder. I advice you to use this structure.
Also please don't user php -S for server, instead use an environment like mamp , wamp or xampp as server. You will have permission issues and ownership issues. Hope it helps.

Comment: I thought public assets should be stored within the public folder?

Comment: You can store there as well. But we as a company we don't use that too much. We use the assets from the resources for blade. for example 
{!! HTML::style('resources/admin/assets/css/icons/icons.min.css') !!} to get styles from that, {!! HTML::script('resources/admin/assets/plugins/modernizr/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js') !!} scripts ,  <img src="{{asset('admin/img/avatars/avatar5_big.png')}}" alt="avatar 4"/> for images.

Comment: What would the path to {{asset('admin/img/avatars/avatar5_big.png')}} be when complied to HTML? Or to put it anther way, what would the path be from http:// localhost/ ?

Comment: <img src="http://localhost/resources/assets/admin/img/avatars/avatar5_big.png" alt="Key icon" class="">

Comment: http://localhost:4000/resources/assets/img/1.jpg cannot be found or accessed (i have copied the file into that folder of course) I just get a broken image icon within my blade view.

Comment: I'm using {!! Html::image( URL::asset('resources/assets/img/' . $banner->banner_image))!!} - the returned HTML is as expected and the image is in the folder as your describe, but it will not be found!

Comment: what errors do you get? Did you set the permissions for /storage and bootstrap to 0777 or 0755? chmod -R 0777 storage/ same for bootstrap

Comment: also please remove resources/assets/ leave just img/ as in my example. URL::assets is pointed to resources/assets already

Comment: Done and done. No errors, just a broken image icon. URL::asset('img/' . $banner->banner_image) gives the same result as URL::asset('resources/assets/img/' . $banner->banner_image)

Comment: Sure enough the problem wasn't the code, it was the environment! After I switched over to MAMP it just worked! (using php-S and the laravel server script wasn't dealing with the permissions properly). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

From http://laravel.com/docs/master/structure

> The storage directory contains compiled Blade templates, file based
>   sessions, file caches, and other files generated by the framework

Maybe your {app}/storage folder is having some sort of conflict with your {app}/public/storage folder? Consider using another name for "storing" uploaded file?

Comment: Good point, but its not just the public/storage forlder. I have other folders within the root of /public behaving the same way

Comment: Other folders like what?

Comment: /public/website1/index.html , for example. This works perfectly on the production server, but cannot be found on the localhost server no matter what I do!

Comment: Then let me tell you : you choosed a terrible first example on why you can't access some given folders... what's the url you use to access /public/website1/index.html ?

Comment: website1 is a non-laravel website sitting within the public folder. The reasos for this are covered in many of my previous posts. Suffice to say they are not the subject of discussion here